# "ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here" related to jinja template

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am running an Ansible playbook.  In a YAML file "jinja.yaml", I have the following jinja2 template.

```
{% set cnt = 0 %} 
{% for x in range(4, 20) %}
    {% for y in range(1, 251) %}
        - pool_name: pool_{{ cnt }}
          {% set cnt = cnt + 1 %}
          pool_member: 10.30.{{ x }}.{{ y }}
{% endfor %} {% endfor %}
```

Here is the snippet in the Ansilbe code:

```
tasks:
    - name: XXX
      set_fact:
        members: "{{ lookup('template', 'jinja.yaml') | from_yaml}}"
```

When I ran the Ansible playbook, I got the following error message:

```
 return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 576, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 32:
                        pool_member: 10.30.4.1
                                   ^

fatal: [10.6.177.160]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

I am 99% sure it's the syntax error in the jinja.yaml but I just did not fix it.  Any help will
appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving the wrong problem; if you want a `list[dict]`, then don't try to build yaml text using jinja templating only to later convert it into the actual data structure you wanted: just construct the `list[dict]` you want without the intermediate serialization:

```
- name: XXX
  set_fact:
    members: >-
     {%- set cnt_holder = {"cnt": 0} -%}
     {%- set results = [] -%} 
     {%- for x in range(4, 20) -%}
     {%- for y in range(1, 251) -%}
     {%- set _ = results.append({
        "pool_name": ("pool_%d" | format(cnt_holder.cnt)),
        "pool_member": ("10.30.%d.%d"|format(x, y)),
        }) -%}
     {%- set _ = cnt_holder.update({"cnt": cnt_holder.cnt + 1}) -%}
     {%- endfor -%}
     {%- endfor -%}
     {{ results }}
```

---

As you'll observe, your original code block had a bug: one cannot reassign variables (which goes doubly so from within a lexical block like a `for` loop); that "feature" of jinja2 is actually documented in [the fine manual](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#assignments)

However, you can mutate existing data structures (in fact that is the whole point of `results.append`). So, we are side-stepping jinja2's `set` behavior and storing the mutable `cnt` in a global dict so we *can* mutate it. That's why my `{% set cnt_holder` differs from your syntax